# How to log within a nextTick?

Tags: node.js

I am debugging an issue that causes the stack trace to get lost.

I'd like to be able to log from within `nextTick`.

```
const _nextTick = process.nextTick;

process.nextTick = function (callback) {
  process.stdout.write('bar');

  const args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);

  return _nextTick.apply(this, args);
};

console.log('foo');
```

However, this causes `Maximum call stack size exceeded` error.

```
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at process.nextTick (/Users/gajus/Documents/dev/applaudience/showtime-api/test.js:4:10)
    at onwrite (_stream_writable.js:372:15)
    at WriteStream.Socket._writeGeneric (net.js:727:5)
    at WriteStream.Socket._write (net.js:737:8)
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:329:12)
    at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:315:5)
    at WriteStream.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:241:11)
    at WriteStream.Socket.write (net.js:664:40)
    at process.nextTick (/Users/gajus/Documents/dev/applaudience/showtime-api/test.js:4:18)
    at onwrite (_stream_writable.js:372:15)
```

It appears that `_stream_writable.js` uses `nextTick` internally, which is causing an infinite loop:

```
foo
barbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbarbar/Users/gajus/Documents/dev/applaudience/showtime-api/test.js:4
  process.stdout.write('bar');
```

Is there anything lower level than `process.stdout.write` that could be used to log a message from within `nextTick`?

Comment: You can't globally replace `.nextTick()` with something else and expect wide ranging code that uses it to still work.  That's just not a good way to solve whatever problem you're trying to solve.  If you want a version of nextTick that you can use that logs, then make your own function that logs and calls nextTick and use that new function in your code.  Don't replace the system's nextTick.

Comment: Replacing `nextTick` (among other `process` and event handlers) to capture long stack traces is the standard (the only) way to capture stack traces of async operations. See https://github.com/mattinsler/longjohn for reference.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I could think of is to create an array that keeps track of messages that I want to log and sends them to the `stdout` at a set interval.

```
const _nextTick = process.nextTick;

let logs = [];
let intervalSeen = false;

process.nextTick = function (callback) {
  if (intervalSeen) {
    logs = [];

    intervalSeen = false;
  }

  logs.push('bar');

  const args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);

  return _nextTick.apply(this, args);
};

setInterval(() => {
  intervalSeen = true;

  console.log(logs);
}, 500)

console.log('foo');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this please:

```
var fs = require('fs')
const _nextTick = process.nextTick;
var stream = fs.createWriteStream('blah', {fd: 1})

process.nextTick = function (callback) {
  stream.write('bar')
  const args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)
  return _nextTick.apply(this, args)
}
console.log('foo')
```